# Mergesort problema con su longitud

Tags: javascript

Hola tengo un problema con eso me dice que la longitud no a sido definida y ya intente muchas cosas pero no funciona alguien sabe que puede ser? solo quiero ingresar numero en el `input` y en el `output` me los de ordenados se que esta algo feo pero estoy empezando apenas con este problema luego le agrego diseño y otras funciones que ya probé y funcionan a la perfección ahorita el problema es esto lo publicare en dos parte porque no me deja hacerlo de un golpe.

```
function ordename (arr) {
  if (arr.length === 1) {
    return arr
  }

  const middle = Math.floor(arr.length / 2) //obtiene e lelemento central de la matriz redondeado hacia abajo
  const left = arr.slice(0, middle) // elementos en el lado izquierdo
  const right = arr.slice(middle)  // elementos en el lado derecho

  return merge(ordename(left),ordename(right))
}

// compara los arreglos elemento por elemento y devuelve el resultado concatenado

function merge (left, right) {
    let result = []
    let indexLeft = 0
    let indexRight = 0

    while (indexLeft < left.length && indexRight < right.length) 
    {
      //Si invierto el menor que, del if se ordena de mayor a menor :v
      if (left[indexLeft] < right[indexRight]) {
        result.push(left[indexLeft])
        indexLeft++
      } else {
        result.push(right[indexRight])
        indexRight++
      }
    }

  return result.concat(left.slice(indexLeft)).concat(right.slice(indexRight))
}

const mostrar = (ingresar)

var ingresar = null;

function sub()
{
  ingresar = document.getElementsByName("ingresar")[0].value;
};


<form name="form"  method="get">
    <input type="text" name="ingresar" id="ingresar">
    <h2>ingresar numeros</h2>
</form>

<output type="text" id="salida"></output>

<button 
onclick="sub()
document.getElementById('salida').innerHTML=(ordename(mostrar))">Prueba</button>
```

Comment: Podrias tratar de ordenar tu codigo y tu problema, decirnos donde falla exactamente y contarnos claramente que es lo que pasa...

Comment: losiento por el orden aun no entiendo como usar esta pagina,pero el problema radica en el punto en que hago click en el boton me dice que la longitud no esta definidad pero solo pasa cuando yo ingreso lo numeros desde un input cuando los ingresos directamente en el codigo funciona bien, basicamente lo que quiero que haga es que yo le ingrese numeros el los tome y me los ordene.

Comment: porfa mira [ask]. ordename(mostrar) <- y mostrar que valor tiene? esta desordenado el codigo. Algun experto en js te lo va a explicar mas claro. pero no le estas pasando nada a la funcion ordename

Comment: tenias razón  gracias ya funciono ahora solo le pondré diseño enserio muchas gracias  :D

Comment: Tenes una respuesta valida para la pregunta? o preferis eliminarla?